# Error while installing Etcher in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, etcher

I want to install BalenaEtcher in my system running Ubuntu 20.04. I tried to follow the steps in https://github.com/balena-io/etcher#debian-and-ubuntu-based-package-repository-gnulinux-x86x64 however while adding the GPG key I am getting the following error.

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443 --recv-keys 379CE192D401AB61
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.DjmWpiRvOZ/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443 --recv-keys 379CE192D401AB61
gpg: failed to start the dirmngr '/usr/bin/dirmngr': No such file or directory
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.DjmWpiRvOZ/S.dirmngr' failed: No such file or directory
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
```

Please guys help me out.

**P.S.- I have another system running Kubuntu 20.04, However it seems no issue while installing or using etcher in that system.**

Thanks and Regards

Sabyasachi Rout

Comment: but when i use start up disk creator it turns my flashdrive  into alien. last time I had to google and run some weird commands to re format the drive. so thank you but I prefer using etcher. Or can you help me to run rufus?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with all this flailing about with different USB-making applications?

Comment: yeah M new to linux. Besides I have etcher running in one system. Why can't I run it with another? Can you help me? Cause for some reson I need to make tons of bootable drives.

Comment: Can you help me with the above issue? Its quite important for me to run etcher. Please help me. Being a naive user I wanna keep it simple.

Comment: Both the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator and Balena Etcher are **cloning tools**. This means that they create identical systems on the USB drive (when cloned from the same iso file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an important clue in your output: `'/usr/bin/dirmngr': No such file or directory`  That means `dirmngr` is not installed.

From the `dirmngr` package description:

> dirmngr is used for network access by gpg, gpgsm, and dirmngr-client,
> among other tools.  Unless this package is installed, the parts of
> the GnuPG suite that try to interact with the network will fail.

Install it: Try `sudo apt install dirmngr`, then try adding that key again.

Comment: Thx brother works fine :)